# WordPress Blog Won't Display Post Title, Meta Data, or Comments

Tags: wordpress

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I'm not much of a programmer.

I coded a WordPress site for one of my clients 3 or 4 years back. They asked to have a blog added to their site.

There are several strange things happening that I'm not entirely sure why.

If you go to: http://firstcalliowa.com/blog/

You can see it's not displaying the post title or meta data. Just the post content.

Also, go to: http://firstcalliowa.com/author/austinhudspeth/

So, this is interesting. Here, you can see the post title and edit this link. The post title isn't linked, but that can be fixed. The interesting part is, I don't have an author file made yet. So, I'm not sure why it looks more correct here, but won't pull up the post title on the first link.

Here's my loop code:

```
`   <div id="content">
        <div id="content_container">

       <!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <!-- Test if the current post is in category 3. -->
 <!-- If it is, the div box is given the CSS class "post-cat-three". -->
 <!-- Otherwise, the div box is given the CSS class "post". -->

 <?php if ( in_category('3') ) { ?>
           <div class="post-cat-three">
 <?php } else { ?>
           <div class="post">
 <?php } ?>


 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>


 <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->

 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>


 <!-- Display the Post's content in a div box. -->

 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>


 <!-- Display a comma separated list of the Post's Categories. -->

 <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
 </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->


 <!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>


 <!-- The very first "if" tested to see if there were any Posts to -->
 <!-- display.  This "else" part tells what do if there weren't any. -->
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>


 <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>`
```

Comment: Also, if you go here: http://firstcalliowa.com/sample-blog-post/

You'll see the COMMENTS header in red. This should be loading Facebook comments. It's not though. I've tried 4 or 5 different Facebook comment plugins and none are displaying. I'm guessing this is a similar related issue, since everything is related to not displaying. 

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On the first link you provided it doesn't look like the HTML you've provided is being used. Can you do a test edit to make sure the /blog page is actually using the loop you've created? I see an empty .post-header div being outputted but I don't see that anywhere in your loop.